# Can you concat with a space-space

Tags: concatenation

I have looked at several of the concat questions and can't seem to make those solutions work for me.

```
case "tblContestant":
            $sql = "SELECT e.id as Id,@n := @n + 1 n, replace(c.name, ',', ' ') as name, c.address, NULL, c.city, c.state, c.phonenumber, c.email,  c.sanctionbody,     concat(c.id,c.sanctionnumber) as sanctionnumber, mcrc.amount,   c.zip, c.jrboater
                    FROM contestants c 
                    LEFT JOIN main_contestant_register_class mcrc ON mcrc.contestant_id = c.id 
                    LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id = mcrc.event_id, (SELECT @n := 0) m  
                    WHERE e.id = $id";
```

The above gives me the result of combining c.id with c.sanctionnumber (142155) however I would like a space-space between c.id and c.sanctionnumber 
(14 - 2155) or (14-2155) if spaces are not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
case "tblContestant":
            $sql = "SELECT e.id as Id,@n := @n + 1 n, replace(c.name, ',', ' ') as name, c.address, NULL, c.city, c.state, c.phonenumber, c.email,  c.sanctionbody,     concat(c.id,' - '+ c.sanctionnumber) as sanctionnumber, mcrc.amount,   c.zip, c.jrboater
                    FROM contestants c 
                    LEFT JOIN main_contestant_register_class mcrc ON mcrc.contestant_id = c.id 
                    LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id = mcrc.event_id, (SELECT @n := 0) m  
                    WHERE e.id = $id";
```

Comment: Thanks Avi, I have tried that and it does not insert the space-space into my Access database and I am left with 142155 instead of 14 - 2155.

Comment: @Raceman now what you do after running this select query. Are you doing any manipulation of data. Because I can't see any Insert query statement here...

Answer (score 0):

Avi thanks for your help the issue is resolved! I simply changed the + to a , and it is now giving me the desired results.

```
concat(c.id,' - '+ c.sanctionnumber) as sanctionnumber, gives me 142155
concat(c.id,' - ', c.sanctionnumber) as sanctionnumber, gives me 14 - 2155
```